# Does the word "wireable" exist?

Tags: adjectives

My current work is creating a kind of node that is connectable to other nodes. However, since the connection is made by wiring these nodes I always use the word *wireable*.

> This node is wireable to other nodes that are exposing the required interface.

While creating a presentation I recognized that the spelling checker does mark the word as wrong. I first thought that this could be one of the words in which the *e* is dropped but in none of the dictionaries (several Oxford Dictionaries, Merriam Webster, Urban, Wordnik) I found *wireable* or *wirable*. I can only find some unreliable sources, so I wonder if this word does really exist or is just a kind of neologism.

Is it appropriate to use the word *wireable* or should I go with *connectable*?

Comment: +1 for taking the time to list which dictionaries you've already checked. P.S. I couldn't find it in the OED, either, but I don't want to dogmatically claim it's not there; it might be buried under some other entry or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary sources would suggest it's a neologism, as you conjectured. Still, if you want my opinion, I'd keep using it.  For one, it doesn't strike me as unnatural or forced (if anything, I'm a bit surprised to *not* find it listed).  For another, it's not without precedent; the word can be found in some reputable sources (see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=xjPyN9GD9EkC&pg=SA1-PA20&lpg=SA1-PA20&dq=%22wireable%22&source=bl&ots=dwEnrOdj0M&sig=eCs8SDjNm84ZaBfZRdHDbU4jUok&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r1MzUOyxE4SOygHeioDQCQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22wireable%22&f=false) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nr4aAQAAIAAJ&q=%22wireable%22&dq=%22wireable%22&source=bl&ots=J8mPFtNSpa&sig=8LWn8Kt_UEtBV_XKqn0oWHxUaeU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r1MzUOyxE4SOygHeioDQCQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBQ), for instance. I also found a paper entitled *On the structure of three-layer wireable layouts*, published in *Advances in Computing Research* in 1984; it has since been cited by at least three other papers and a 2004 book).

So long as *wireable* seems like a more appropriate word than *connectable* in your context, I'd be bold and use the word.

Answer (score 7):

Since *wire* is a verb<sup>[1]</sup>, and one of its meanings is

> To fasten, join, or secure using wire; to fit or provide with wire or wires.

I'm sure you can use it figuratively.

It is fine to turn verbs into adjectives by adding *-able*, e.g. *drivable*, *runnable*, *stoppable*, etc., so your readers should have no problem understanding *wirable* or *wireable*.

As an alternative, if you'd like to keep within the scope of your spell checker:

> This node can be wired to other nodes...

With regard as to whether *wireable* is a known word; I cannot find *wireable* in a dictionary, but [this Google books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireable&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=ObzyPd5hDbe3GWLPBiJ4Zw&ds=bo&pq=wireable&cp=6&gs_id=1k3&xhr=t&q=nodes+wireable&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=nodes+wireable&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5a8f014602616f53&biw=1280&bih=933) shows the use of *wire* and *wireability* in conjunction with *node*. So it's not picked up enough momentum to enter mainstream dictionaries yet, but it's not unheard of in the sense you suggest.

[1]: "wire, v.". OED Online. June 2012. Oxford University Press. http://oed.com/view/Entry/229450?rskey=tufOfz&result=3&isAdvanced=false (accessed August 21, 2012).